# How to repeat an instruction of raw_input

Tags: python, notepad

I have a question: how to repeat an instruction of raw_input in python 2.7.5?

```
print("This is a NotePad")
main = raw_input()
```

this is the code(I started 3 minutes ago.)
I can't find an answer to my question on Google.

This is the code with me trying but suffering

```
print("This is a NotePad")
main = raw_input()

for i in range(12000):
    main
```

The error is Process finished with exit code 0
Okay, it's not an error but it's not what I was expecting.

Comment: you need to call `main` the same way you called `raw_input` (they're both functions)

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you possibly would want to be using Python 2 when it's been dead and deprecated for over 3 years

Comment: `for i in range(12000): raw input()`? Also you should be using Python 3.

Comment: `main` isn't a function; it's `str` *returned* by a function.

Comment: What *were* you expecting? Assume Python 3 and replace `raw_input` with `input`, and this question still isn't really asking anything.

Comment: Are you expecting 12,000 calls to `raw_input`? `main = raw_input` and `for i in range(12000): main()`.

Comment: If you want to call `raw_input` 12,000 times, just put the call in the loop: `for i in range(12000): raw_input()`. But probably you want to store the input somewhere, like appending it to a list. It would help a lot if you were to explain what are you trying to do, and what's your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

`main = raw_input()` does not make `main` a "macro" equivalent to `raw_input()`. It assigns the return value of a single call of `raw_input` to the name `main`. The closest thing to what you appear to be trying to do is to assign the value of the name `raw_input` itself (the function) to the name `main`, then *call* that function in the loop.

```
main = raw_input  # Another name for the same function

for i in range(12000):
    # Resolve the name lookup, then call the resulting function
    main()
```

Comment: what di I need to write?

Comment: What do you mean? This is complete code, though it doesn't do anything interesting. It will ask you for 12000 lines of input, then exit.